# Nodejs sending basic webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm following this [tutorial](http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/) to learn about Nodejs and Io socket.
But i'm having a problem with loading the page socket.html.

My goal is to let him print this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>This is our socket.html file</body>
</html>
```

But the result is an empty page.

I tried to let him print different things as you can see in commentary in my code but nothing seems to work. I'm sure the code is reaching the right loop because he prints "enterLoop" in my console as expected.

Why is this not working?

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            //fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                fs.readFile(__dirname + "/socket.html", function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                }
                else{

                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                    //response.writeHead(404);
                    //response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 4055");
                    //response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    //response.write(data); 
                    //response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    //response.write('hello world'); 
                    console.log("enterLoop");
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            break;
    }
    response.end();
});

server.listen(8001);

io.listen(server);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the file in asynchronously, so `response.end()` is getting called before it can read the file and write the response. Move the `response.end()` to within the callback and it should work.

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            response.end();
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            //fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                fs.readFile(__dirname + "/socket.html", function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                    response.end();
                }
                else{

                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                    //response.writeHead(404);
                    //response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 4055");
                    //response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    //response.write(data); 
                    //response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    //response.write('hello world'); 
                    console.log("enterLoop");
                    response.end();
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            response.end();
            break;
    }

});

server.listen(8001);

io.listen(server);
```